# Parent $scope value not showing in ng model after html $compile in angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I'm trying to generate HTML and input control from Angular Scope Isolated Directive in Typescript and modeling that input control with parent scope property.

The Problem i'm getting that although Angular $compiles the html and but the model value doesnt show in input control BUT CAN BE SEEN ON BROWSER CONSOLE.

Following is my **angular Directive in typescript** :

```
class InputControl implements ng.IDirective {


    restrict = "E";
    scope = {
        field: "=field"
    };
    templateUrl = "";
    controller = ["$scope","$sce","$compile", ($scope: any,$sce:ng.ISCEService, $compile : ng.ICompileService) => {
        var controlHTML = "";
        var jsonObj = "$scope.$parent.$parent.sheetModel.model." + eval("$scope.field.Property");
        switch($scope.field.PropertyDetail.Type)
        {
            case "string":{

                controlHTML = $compile("<input type='text' class='form-control' ng-model='"+jsonObj+"'></input>'")($scope)[0].outerHTML;
                break;
            }

        }
        //$scope.html = controlHTML;
         $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(controlHTML);
    }];

    controllerAs = "inputcontroller";

    constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService , private $sce:ng.ISCEService , private $compile : ng.ICompileService) {
        var a : InputControl = this;
        a.templateUrl=$sce.trustAsUrl("http://"+window.location.host +"/AngularApp/Templates/inputcontrol.html");
    }

    link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctrl: any, $compile : ng.ICompileService) => {
    };

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = ($location: ng.ILocationService , $sce : ng.ISCEService,$compile : ng.ICompileService) => new InputControl($location,$sce,$compile);
        directive.$inject = ["$location","$sce","$compile"];
        return directive;
    }
}

angular.module("SheetApp").directive("inputControl", InputControl.factory());
```

**HTML TEMPLATE**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="field.Property" ng-bind="field.PropertyDetail.Caption"></label>
<span ng-bind-html="html"></span>
```

INPUT GENerated :

[image]

On debug , it has value but not model into the control

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about your case. `$scope.field.Property` is equal to `Inspection.InspectorName`, right? If so why have you `label for="field.Property"` then? Why cannot you just use field as model?

Comment: yes $scope.field.Property  is equal to Inspection.InspectorName.
jsonObj is string. but i run the jsonObj value in console i get the TEST result but there i wont get that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it started working, when i changed line from

```
var jsonObj = "$scope.$parent.$parent.sheetModel.model." + eval("$scope.field.Property");
```

to

```
var jsonObj = "$parent.$parent.sheetModel.model." + eval("$scope.field.Property");
```